# Is a method on a singleton class (Reference Type) accessed by two threads at the same time thread safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

Hoping you can help me clear up my understanding on thread safety and calls to methods on a Singleton.

I've outlined a simple scenario below. My question is: if ProcessorOne and ProcessorTwo are running at the same time, and if the DatabaseIntegration class is a reference type and is a singleton (managed by CastleWindsor) and ProcessorOne and ProcessorTwo share this singleton instance of DataBaseIntegration, then is there potential for the Entity saved by ProcessorOne to have the name from ProcessorTwo?

Meaning can the Entity parameter passed to databaseIntegration.Save(Entity entity) by ProcessorOne be modified by the thread that ProcessorTwo is running on once the call to the method has been made by ProcessorOne thread?

```
public class ProcessorOne
{
    private readonly DatabaseIntegration databaseIntegration;
    public ProcessorOne(DatabaseIntegration databaseIntegration)
    {
        this.databaseIntegration = databaseIntegration;
    }

    public void Process()
    {                                  
       Entity entity = new Entity() 
       {
           Name="NameOne"
       };

       this.dataBaseIntegration.Save(entity);
    }
}

public class ProcessorTwo
{
    private readonly DatabaseIntegration dataBaseIntegration;
    public ProcessorTwo(DatabaseIntegration dataBaseIntegration)
    {
        this.dataBaseIntegration = dataBaseIntegration;
    }

    public void Process()
    {            
       Entity entity = new Entity() 
       {
           Name="NameTwo"
       };

       this.dataBaseIntegration.Save(entity);
    }
}

public class DatabaseIntegration 
{     
    public void Save(Entity entity)
    {            
         using (DbContext context = new DbContext(sqlConnection))
         {
             context.Entity.Add(entity);
             context.SaveChanges();                 
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Although both `ProcessorOne` and `ProcessorTwo` both share the same reference to `DatabaseIntegration`, and they can both run the `DatabaseIntegration.Save` method at the same time, the `DatabaseIntegration.Save` method is thread-safe.

It is safe to construct two `DbContexts` which share the same connection, and use them at the same time - they won't interfere with each other. Your database takes care of making sure that two insertions don't interfere with each other.

If your `DatabaseIntegration.Save` method did some things which weren't thread-safe, such as if you had a field on `DatabaseIntegration` which was modified by `Save` outside of a lock, then you might introduce thread-safety issues.